# AVL tree : adding a new field to each node : the "size" of its tree , while Insert action

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, avl-tree

I'm trying to update the `Insert` action while inserting a new element into an AVL tree .
The update to the `insert` action will add to each node the size of its rooted tree .

Now ,since I insert my elements bottom-up , then if I just add a `+1` for every node that I pass while touring up , then in some cases this wouldn't work , for example when I need to balance the tree after the new tree is not balanced , since I change pointers , then the calculation wouldn't be correct .

Any idea or hint how can I do that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be to modify it simply with the definition of the size.

Give the leaves `size = 1`, and for each node that is a part of the tour to the root, or was a part of a roll (from buttom up) set:

```
size(v) = size(v.left) + size(v.right) + 1
            ^                 ^          ^
        size of left     size of right   size of "root"
           subtree        subtree
```

This will be correct because you modify in each step all the vertices that were changed, and since you do it buttom-up, the size can be calculated correctly for each node you modify.

Note that it does not affect complexity, since for each such vertex - you are doing constant number of OPs, and you are doing it only to vertices you would have traversed anyway.